# Create a new row in another table with the change in status in some other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a requests table with status as a field in it and an encounters table. Status field displays a dropdown from status table . What I want is that with every change in the status a new record is created in the encounter table which keeps the record of all the statuses for each request. I need a recommendation for how this can be achieved.

request_form

```
<%= form_for([@client, @request], local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :status_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :status_id, Status.all, :status, :status, {prompt: "Select"}, autofocus:true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

encounter table schema

```
create_table "encounters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "request_id"
    t.date "status_change_date"
    t.integer "admin_id"
    t.string "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

request.rb

```
has_many :encounters
```

encounter.rb

```
belongs_to :request
```

request.rb

```
after_update :create_encounter
def create_encounter
    if self.changes.keys.include?(:status_id)?
      puts "updated"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rails model call back

on request.rb

```
after_update :create_encounter

def create_encounter
  if self.changes.keys.include?(:status_id)
   # your code to create encounter related to request
  end
```

end

Comment: I just tried it with putting puts "updated" in the function but it throws up an error. unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do

Comment: I want it to create a row in the encounter table when a request is created and keep on adding new records with every change in the status of the request.

Comment: undefined method `changes'

Answer (score 0):

On request.rb, you have an ? mark at the end of `self.changes.keys.include?(:status_id)?`, which is rising an error. Let it like `self.changes.keys.include?(:status_id)`.

Comment: I want it to create a row in the encounter table when a request is created and keep on adding new records with every change in the status of the request.